# How to merge 2 Spark dataframe using if else conditions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can we merge 2 dataframes and form a new data using conditions.for eg.
if data is present in dataframe B , use the row from dataframe B else use data from dataframe A.

DataFrame A

```
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
| Name|           LastTime|Duration|Status|
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
|  Bob|2015-04-23 12:33:00|       1|logout|
|Alice|2015-04-20 12:33:00|       5| login|
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
```

DataFrame B

```
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
| Name|           LastTime|Duration|Status|
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
|  Bob|2015-04-24 00:33:00|       1|login |
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
```

I want to form a new dataframe by using whole data in Dataframe A but update rows using data in B

```
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
| Name|           LastTime|Duration|Status|
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
|  Bob|2015-04-24 00:33:00|       1|login |
|Alice|2015-04-20 12:33:00|       5| login|
+-----+-------------------+--------+------+
```

I tried full outer join as

`val joined = df.as("a").join(df.as("b")).where($"a.name" === $"b.name","outer")`

But it resulted in 1 row with duplicate columns.How can I ignore the row in first table if there is one corresponding row is present in second.

Comment: Please reformat your question and complete it with what you have tried so far (some code) !

Comment: Classic use case of a full outer join :)

Answer (score 1):

val combined_df = dfa.join(dfb,Seq("Name"),"right").select(dfa("Name"), coalesce(dfa("LastTime"), dfb("LastTime")),  coalesce(dfa("Duration"), dfb("Duration")),coalesce(dfa("Status"), dfb("Status")))

Comment: Please write some description about this.